# Find row number of the value that is found by 'Find' function

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code, trying to find the row number of the value that is found by Find() previously.

```
Dim rng as range
Dim fndrng as range

Set rng = Range(cells(row1, col), Cells(row2, col))
max_value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng) 
    
Set fndrng = rng.find(what:=max_value, LookIn:=xlValues)
answer = fndrng.row
```

My code doesn't work, but instead print the error saying,
"Run-time error '91':
Object variable or with block variable not set"

It seems to me that fndrng is always empty after running the line<rng.find(what:=max_value, LookIn:=xlValues)>. However, if I manually use 'find' function in the worksheet by 'ctrl+F', it can find the value(s)!

Is there anyone who can help me out here? I have no idea how come it isn't working. It would be appreciated if you can share better alternatives when it comes to getting row number of the value I am looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: There can be quite a number of reasons, why your value isn't found. Why don't you share the rest of the code and maybe a screenshot of the relevant worksheet, so that we get a chance of solving your problem.

Answer (score 2):

With the shared code, I believe you could have an issue with the following line:

```
Set rng = Range(cells(row1, col), Cells(row2, col)
```

You did not share what kind of object are  `row1`, `row2` and `col` in your code. Therefore, I'm going to make assumptions for the code you shared to work, declaring those object as `Long`:

```
Dim row1 As Long
Dim row2 As Long
Dim col As Long

row1 = 1
row2 = 20
col = 1

Set rng = Range(cells(row1, col), Cells(row2, col))
```

This would make `rng` to be equivalent to `"A1:A20"` You can of course modify this to your desired range, and maybe add a `col1` and `col2` instead of a single column to expand the range. We now look for the `max_value` in the `"A1:A20"` range. Below the test code I used and the simulation in my worksheet:

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim fndrng As Range

Dim row1 As Long
Dim row2 As Long
Dim col As Long

row1 = 1
row2 = 20
col = 1

Set rng = Range(Cells(row1, col), Cells(row2, col))

max_value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
        
Set fndrng = rng.Find(what:=max_value, LookIn:=xlValues)
answer = fndrng.row

MsgBox answer

End Sub
```

Below the values in my worksheet, the `max_value` would be 100 located in row 9

[image]

The MsgBox received:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's not somethings as simple as DTLC_max vs max_value

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `rng` as `Range` type. Try below sub then adjust the code to your own.

```
Sub FindMaxValueRow()
Dim rng As Range

    With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A500")
        Set rng = .Find(2, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox rng.Row
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

To search max value use this line `Set rng = .Find(max_value, LookIn:=xlValues)`

Source of code to Microsoft [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who has been struggling to find the solution to the same problem as I did and finally got to here, I figured out that the data type of 'max_value' needs to be 'variant' in this case, and it was 'long' at first.

This is how I solved out this question, and I hope this can help anyone who suffers.